# About ISTQB certificate

Tags: istqb

1. How do I get the ISTQB certification over the Internet?
2. Is it available for Israel's resident?
3. How do I prove my identification?

Comment: I do not think you can get a ISTQB certificate over the internet. You will need to attend an exam session in person. It is available to everyone. You will need to show them your driver's licence or passport as your ID.

Comment: I think these questions are best asked by someone who sells / provides ISTQB certification. Not here. Voting to close.

Comment: @ChrisKenst - while I agree with you that asking some company which in in the business of certification is right and obvious choice, question is relevant to our audience and should stay. With luck, next person thinking about asking it will find it.

Comment: @Shay - Please let us know what you figured out, you can answer your own question (and gain some good karma for it)

Comment: It is about an specific test exam which should be asked to the relevant entity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too geographically-specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can register via the internet for ISTQB Certification. You would then go to an exam center, where you would need to show an official photo identification.

There are two exam centers in Israel:
- John Bryce - Mediatech Hi-Tech    46 Hahistadrot Street   Haifa   N/A Israel  Map 
- John Bryce Training LTD   Homa U Migdal St. 29    Tel Aviv    N/A Israel

To register, go to https://www.astqb.org/get-certified/istqb-software-tester-certification-exam-registration/ - choose the Online Electronic Exam via an Exam Center option.

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. Yes
3. ID card ?

[call the ITCB](http://www.itcb.org.il/)